# Not able to Upload 64-bit build in Google play Store

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, 32bit-64bit, google-play-console

We are trying to upload the 64bit & 32bit build, according to the recent Google policy change.

We have included respective abifilter "`ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'`" in the Build.gradle.

We were able to generate the build but when we upload the build to Play console for Beta review. It gives a warning saying  "**Release is not compliant with 64-bit Google Requirement**". 
[image]

We tried all approach, generating 4 builds (`x86,x86_64,armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a`), generating two builds or uploading the universal build with all abifilter, it gives the same warning. We tried all possible approaches.

Please help us out in perfect steps of uploading the build to Play store or if we are making any mistake in generating the build please do let us know on that ends also.

Please check the build.gradle code:

```
     {
         minSdkVersion 19
         applicationId 'com.xxx.xxx'
         targetSdkVersion 28
         testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
         versionCode 32 // 27-30
         versionName '1.2.1'
         ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
         proguardFile 'proguard-android.txt'
      }
```

Also, we tried with another approach given below:

```
  splits {
    // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
    abi {
        // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
        enable true
        // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
        // want APKs for x86 and x86_64.
        // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
        reset()
        // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
        include "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a"

        // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
        universalApk true
    }
}



ext.abiCodes = ["x86": 1, "x86_64": 2, "armeabi-v7a": 3, "arm64-v8a": 4]

import com.android.build.OutputFile

// For each APK output variant, override versionCode with a combination of
// ext.abiCodes * 1000 + variant.versionCode. In this example, variant.versionCode
// is equal to defaultConfig.versionCode. If you configure product flavors that
// define their own versionCode, variant.versionCode uses that value instead.
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

// Assigns a different version code for each output APK
// other than the universal APK.
variant.outputs.each { output ->

    // Stores the value of ext.abiCodes that is associated with the ABI for this variant.
    def baseAbiVersionCode =
            // Determines the ABI for this variant and returns the mapped value.
            project.ext.abiCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI))

    // Because abiCodes.get() returns null for ABIs that are not mapped by ext.abiCodes,
    // the following code does not override the version code for universal APKs.
    // However, because we want universal APKs to have the lowest version code,
    // this outcome is desirable.
    if (baseAbiVersionCode != null) {

        // Assigns the new version code to versionCodeOverride, which changes the version code
        // for only the output APK, not for the variant itself. Skipping this step simply
        // causes Gradle to use the value of variant.versionCode for the APK.
        output.versionCodeOverride =
                baseAbiVersionCode * 1 + variant.versionCode
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple of days of struggle found the working solution here: [diego.org](http://diego.org/2016/09/20/embedding-crosswalk-in-android-studio-updated/)

Basically, if you need the 64-bit library you first need to download the correct library from the source site(Respective library site). Check whether you are using the version of the Library whose 64-bit library is available or not.

Then install it to the local maven repository(Basically your Local Maven will be used in generating the 64-bit apk's):

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId= (library group for e.g.org.xwalk) -DartifactId= (library name for e.g.xwalk_core_library) \
-Dversion=(version no for e.g.23.53.589.4-64bit) -Dpackaging=aar  \
-Dfile=(file name for e.g.xwalk_core_library-23.53.589.4-64bit.aar) \
-DgeneratePom=true
```

And update your build gradle so that the repositories point to your local maven repo:

```
repositories {
   mavenLocal()
}
```

and you compile the correct lib:

```
compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4' // Use this library for generating "armeabi-v7a" & "x86" build
compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4-64bit' // Use this library for generating "arm64-v8a" & "x86_64" build
```

Use the gradle Config:

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64' // For your flavor or defaultConfig
```

Following these steps will generate two builds one with **32bit** and another with **64bit**, doing these will also help you to avoid errors like "**Fully Shadowed apk**"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**FIRST OF ALL YOU SET Universal APK = False**

*Follow This Gradle*

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "photo.abc.video"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk {
        moduleName "andengine_shared"
    }
}
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}

splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        universalApk false
    }
 }
}

ext.abiCodes = ['x86':1, 'x86_64':2, 'armeabi-v7a':3, 'arm64-v8a':4]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but even if I say universalApk = false, still I will have 4 builds generated if I use either of this 64bit build it shows the same warning.

Comment: first compare my gradle and yours and than do some change after tell me

Comment: It's exactly the same, just the universalApk flag is different.

Comment: you haven'n lint option and remove ndk.abifilter from default config

Comment: you use any native code in your app if yes so must use ndk.AbiFilter Otherwise not need ndkfilter got it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Android App Bundle Publishing](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle) method to avoid these errors.
Your application will be built for all types of devices by google.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but due to some complexity of the App, we won't be able to use the Android App Bundle approach.

Answer (score 1):

i fix  my proplem it is easy you dont  need mvn install:install-file

just go to  download  page

```
https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/21.51.546.7/
```

and  download  2 library

1- 32 bit

2- 64 bit

this
xwalk_core_library-21.51.546.7-arm64.aar
and  this 
 xwalk_core_library-21.51.546.7-x86.aar

after download  you need  to  open file  use  winrar

take  the  x86 libart out  and  add to   arm64 file

so now  we have  2  library on the file  32 bit and  64 bit

[image]

now  add  this library   to android stiduo

file - new - new module  - jar/aar

add you libary

after that

[image]

add your library on your project

[image]

in your build gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 17
        versionName "3.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86' ,'x86_64'
        }
```

that all

apk analyze yes you have  2 library    32 bit and  64 bit now  you can Update your application

[image]

Comment: This is probably the cleanest way to do this currently, especially since there is no support for this unless you want to do multiple APK builds. Funny enough I had this exact issue with a legacy project using the same xwalk library as well, so this answer saved my day!