# How to version up android app to x64 architecture?

Tags: android, android-studio, 64-bit, .so

Currently, I'm maintaining an Android project, my project use some native library (.so file in "armeabi-v7a" architecture). Recently I receive the warning of Google that my app need to be versioned up to support x64 architecture.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

As I researched on internet, I need to version up all of my .so file to "armeabi-v8a" before rebuild my project to support x64 architecture.
Now I'm facing 2 problems with this:

1. In my plugin project (project that generate .so file), I don't know how to version up my .so file to "armeabi-v8a"

In my build.gradle file, I added the following code to "android.productFlavors"

```
ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v8a")
```

but when I try "Make Project" button, I couldn't find new ".so" file in anywhere ?

2. My plugin project also use some other .so file as library, so I also need to version all of those .so file to armeabi-v8a before generate my .so file in armeabi-v8a. Do i have right understanding ?

Is my solution for version up my Android app to support x64 architecture correctly ?

Anyone have knowledge about this, please help me.

Comment: Add this Gradle setting and try it ==> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56592248/not-able-to-upload-64-bit-build-in-google-play-store/56592349#56592349

Comment: @SanjayHadiya: Do you mean add it to the project that use to generate .so file ? or my main project ?

Comment: yes, just try it because it's work for me ....

Comment: @SanjayHadiya: I add your code in to my project and create apk OK. But when I start app, it crashed, do you know why ?

Comment: show me your full log